# How to start Empathy hidden?

Tags: 14.04, 14.10, 15.04, empathy

How to start Empathy in hidden mode in Ubuntu?  If you auto-start Empathy in hidden mode, you can not open the Contacts window, even though Empathy is running in the background.

Note, this was possible in previous versions of Ubuntu using `empathy -h` or `empathy --start-hidden`. (See [Bug 1179180](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/1179180)).

Comment: Even if this *was* only applicable to a now-EoL release, it would have been wrong to close it, because 13.04 was on-topic when the question was originally asked. *New* questions about end-of-life releases are off-topic, but [old questions don't become retroactively off-topic this way](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8188/22949).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a workaround for this problem...

**Step 1**

Install xdotool...

```
$ sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

**Step 2**

To start empathy in hidden mode just for yourself...

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart
$ cp /usr/share/applications/empathy.desktop ~/.config/autostart
$ gedit ~/.config/autostart/empathy.desktop
```

...OR....

To start empathy in hidden mode for all users...

```
$ cp /usr/share/applications/empathy.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart
$ sudo gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/empathy.desktop
```

**Step 3**

In section `[Desktop Entry]`

Replace...

```
Exec=empathy
```

With...

```
Exec=sh -c 'empathy & xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class "empathy" windowmove 25 25 windowunmap'
```

Finally, save your changes; log out and log back in.  You will see the Empathy window "flash" for split-second and then it will disappear.  Empathy will continue to run in the background, and you will be able to open the Empathy contacts window (from the unity indicator) whenever you want.

*Note: If you don't like the command line, install `xdotool` using the Software Center.  Then use the Startup Applications GUI from the Dash to to create a new launcher called "Empathy," and enter the following as the command: `sh -c 'empathy & xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class "empathy" windowmove 25 25 windowunmap'`.*

Comment: You can fix those code tags in your answer by putting an blank line before each one.

Comment: Your workaround is **FANTASTIC**. I included the command in my custom startup script that also launches Skype and it works perfectly. :)

Comment: Andrea, Skype has a "Start Skype minimized in the system tray" option that works fine in Ubuntu, in case you didn't already know.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean that I also use xdotool for Skype, just that I launch both of them at the same time. :P Sorry for not being clear. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If [that workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/308388/22949) doesn't work try this in the `Exec=` line when you edit `/etc/xdg/autostart/empathy.desktop` (or `/usr/share/applications/empathy.desktop`):

```
sh -c 'empathy & sleep 5 && xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class "empathy" windowunmap'
```

This is similar but not the same:

- It attempts to add a five-second pause between starting Empathy and sending simulated input to it with [`xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/xdotool.1.html).
- It also uses only the `windowunmap` action, rather than the preceding `windowmove` action which is less essential.

Comment: Good suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2020, **--start-hidden** functionality is provided with the standard version of Empathy in the Ubuntu 20.04 standard package repos.

Empathy 3.12.14 usage :

```
$ empathy --help
Usage:
  empathy [OPTION…] - Empathy IM Client

Help Options:
  -?, --help                 Show help options
  --help-all                 Show all help options
  --help-gtk                 Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  -n, --no-connect           Don't connect on startup
  -h, --start-hidden         Don't display the contact list or any other dialogs on startup
  -p, --show-preferences     
  -v, --version              
  --display=DISPLAY          X display to use
```

There is a **--start-hidden** option which should provide the functionality you need.

Follow the standard way to add this to your start up programs for the window manager you are using. For xfce4:

`$ xfce4-session-settings`

Then add `empathy -h` to the list in the *Application Autostart* section.