# I want to open Thunderbird at system start up, but keep it minimised

Tags: startup, unity-dash, thunderbird

I am running Ubuntu 13.04, and wish to do the following:

Start Thunderbird at boot up - I am aware of how to do this and need no support with this.

As well as running at start up, I also want the Thunderbird window to remain minimised to the Dash -- this is the area that I am unable to find a solution for and am not sure if it is possible

Really appreciate any guidance - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this solution I posted to do the same thing for Empathy...

[How to start Empathy hidden in 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308385/how-to-start-empathy-hidden-in-13-04/308388#308388)

(One word of caution, however, thunderbird takes a while to connect, so you may notice some sluggishness when you login into your desktop.)