# Minimize or hide the Firefox window on startup

Tags: firefox, minimize

i have created a startup script for Firefox..is there any addition to minimize or hide automatically on startup?

Comment: Not natively possible in Gnome Shell, but here is a hack that uses `xdotool --unmap`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/308385/how-to-start-empathy-hidden